# single picture displaying upside down in bootstrap responsive mobile (iPhone 5)

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I have a link that grabs info from sql and an image folder, it's been working great for everything except I ran across one image that flips upside down on mobile and not anywhere else

I have no clue whats causing this, was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: the image looks fine to me on my phone.

Comment: My iPhone 5 running 6.1.3 shows it upside down :(

Comment: Maybe it is because I am not using an iPhone. I am using Android Chrome. Try clearing your cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, it was due to the image size. I reduced the image size and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried converting image? Sometimes something goes wrong with image encoding, and that could cause errors like this. Try to save your image to .bmp (or any other loseless format), and then to .jpg again. Hope it helps!

Comment: Resaving the images fixed the same error happening to me a while ago.

Comment: Figured it out, it was due to the image size. I reduced the image size and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Andrew - if you have found a solution, please provide is as separate answer (not comment) to help out future visitors find your solution easier! Also mark your answer as "solved" when that option becomes avaiable. Thanks!